# Transfer Multiple people picker column's value from one site to another

Tags: development, web-services, object-model

I have a column of multiple people picker called Likes in 2007 sharepoint site  which stores n number of people.
Now i want to programmatically transfer it's content to sharepoint 2010 site.

Problem is the id of users is not the same in both sites
How to do it. i have used SPFieldUserValueCollection by first retreiving it's content using webservice and then adding new items but it will not work because of user ids are not same.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When moving your values, use domain\account rather than ids.

Something like this:

```
// ....
var userValueCollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(
    itemFrom2007.Web, 
    Convert.ToString(itemFrom2007[myFieldGuid]));

string userValueCollectionAsLogins = "";
foreach (SPFieldUserValue userValue in userValueCollection)
{
    userValueCollectionAsLogins += "-1;#" + userValue.User.LoginName + ";#";
}

var userField2010 = itemFrom2010.Fields[myFieldGuid] as SPFieldUser;
userField2010.ParseAndSetValue(itemFrom2010, userValueCollectionAsLogins);
// ...
itemFrom2010.Update();
```

Comment: SPUserField is showing error.Any specific dll to be added?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `SPFieldUser` of course! I corrected the post